# Bootstrap: scrollbar disappears after closing modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I'm using Boostrap 3 and I have one modal displaying some HTML contents, and it has a scrollbar since all content doesn't fit into viewport. Inside this modal, there's a link to open another modal. Everything works fine, the second modal opens but when I close it, the scrollbar disappears and I can't scroll on the first modal (it's not possible to scroll with scroll wheel on mouse as well). Here's the code for modals:

```
<!-- First modal for creating voucher -->

<div class="modal fade" id="createVoucherModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createVoucherModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 800px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Zatvori</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Izradi voucher</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="voucher-modal-body" class="modal-body" style="margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;">
                <!-- here goes dinamically created content (with jQuery) -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="modal-create-pdf" href="" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="">Kreiraj PDF</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Second modal for editing note voucher -->

<div class="modal fade" id="editVoucherNoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editVoucherNoteModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Zatvori</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Uredi bilješke</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="voucher-modal-body" class="modal-body">
                <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="voucher_note_input"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary voucher_note_edit_button">Spremi</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Body of the first modal is empty because it's dinamically generated with jQuery, but here's the link for opening second modal

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editVoucherNoteModal" id="voucher_note_edit" style="display: none;">Uredi</a>
```

Pictures are linked, since I can't upload them there without 10 reputation:

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPGC0.jpg)

First one shows first modal opened, on the second picture there's second modal opened and on the third picture the second modal is closed and there's no scrollbar.

Answer (score 10):

I was impatient so I kept trying and finally found a solution which works. I added

```
style="overflow-y: scroll;"
```

to the first modal DIV element, now it looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" style="overflow-y: scroll;" id="createVoucherModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createVoucherModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 800px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Zatvori</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Izradi voucher</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="voucher-modal-body" class="modal-body" style="margin: 20px 40px 20px 40px;">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="modal-create-pdf" href="" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="">Kreiraj PDF</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it works!

Comment: you sir are a god among men! You wouldn't believe how long i've been trying to solve this!

Comment: In my case I only have one modal and when I close it, the body content loses its scrollbar. Tested on a nexus 7 with Chrome browser. Your little hack solves the issue but would you know what causes this bug?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked this question because I didn't have any idea what could be the problem. Maybe it would be better to ask Bootstrap support if exists. As I can see, there's an option to report a issue on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to add the removed 'modal-open' class from the 'body' after the second modal is hidden:

```
$( '#editVoucherNoteModal' ).on( 'hidden.bs.modal' , function() {
    $( 'body' ).addClass( 'modal-open' );
} );
```

This works for your example, but if you have another modal opened you can use this workaround:

```
$( '#editVoucherNoteModal' ).on( 'hidden.bs.modal' , function() {
    if ( $( '.modal:visible' ).length ) {
        $( 'body' ).addClass( 'modal-open' );
    }
} );
```

Note: There's gonna be a 'weird' (and I say weird to my standards) behavior with the scroll bar and right padding of the body that might need a lookup to the Bootstrap JS Code, but for a quick use I give what it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  })

  $(".modal [data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal('hide');
  });
```

It will serve for any *modal whithin a modal* that comes to appear.
Note that the first its closed so the second to appear.
No changes in the Bootstrap structure.